# Using jQuery to get DDL selected value inside nested listview

Tags: c#, jquery, listview, selector, ddl

I have a nested ASP.NET ListView, the outer one presenting groups of questions, and the inner one presenting distinct questions within the group. Some of the questions are presented as drop down lists. I want to detect the selected value on change without doing a postback. I have seen lots of references that look like "$(#control).val()" but I need a bit more flexibility.

I am adding the JavaScript in the C# code and it looks like this:

```
js = string.Format("javaScript:setInputSelectOption('{0}'); return false;", hidSelector.Value);
ddlInputSelectOptions.Attributes.Add("onchange", js);
```

The resultant aspx file contains this generated code;

```
<div id='Management_q2'>
<input type="hidden" name="ctl00$body$lstExecutive$ctrl1$hidSelector" id="ctl00_body_lstExecutive_ctrl1_hidSelector" value="Management" />
    <select name="ctl00$body$lstExecutive$ctrl1$ddlInputSelectOptions"
  id="ctl00_body_lstExecutive_ctrl1_ddlInputSelectOptions" 
  onchange="javaScript:setInputSelectOption('Management'); return false;">
    <option value="0">Not Present</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="1">Occasionally</option>
    <option value="2">Customarily and Regularly</option>
    <option value="3">Constantly</option>
</select>
</div>
```

My .js file contains this code:

```
function setInputSelectOption(question) {
    var n = $('[id$=' + question + '_q2]>[id$=hidSelector]').val();
    var v = $('[id$=' + question + '_q2]>[id$=ddlInputSelectOptions]');
    setDDLData(n, v);
}
```

Using Chrome, I have tried these variants on the "var v = " line with the corresponding results:

> $('[id$=' + question + '_q2]>[id$=ddlInputSelectOptions]'):
>   d.fn.d.init[1] $('[id$=' + question +
>   '_q2]>[id$=ddlInputSelectOptions]').value: undefined $('[id$=' +
>   question + '_q2]>[id$=ddlInputSelectOptions]').val(): ""

So I am (yet again) looking for the right incantion to utter to jQuery so that it will return the selected value from the DDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest keeping it simple. Add a data- attribute to the DDL you wish to get the values from. Use jQuery to find the value.

```
ddl.Attributes.Add("data-ddl","reference");
```

Then in JS.

```
// get value
var ddlValue = $("select[data-ddl='reference']").val();
// assign value
$("select[data-ddl='reference']").val("option");
```

Also, if the JS is only for UI logic, it's best to keep it out of the C# code and run it on the page ready using jQuery. So in your JS file.

```
$(function(){
    // bind a function to the select change event
    $("select[data-ddl='reference']").change(function(){
        // insert UI logic here
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't fully understand this, but then I am still on a steep jQuery learning curve. Anyway, thank you WCM